# How can i display the details for the item as well as other database information

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm fairly new to asp.net mvc and In my details page I'm trying to add links to other details pages in my details page. As well as having the information about the selected page. But i'm not sure how to go about it in the controller or the view.

Here is the controller code for the details page:

```
 public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Posts posts = db.Posts.Find(id);
        if (posts == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(posts);
    }
```

I tried adding something like this into it:

```
var posts = (from p in db.Posts
                    orderby p.DateAdded descending
                    select p).Take(4);
```

But i havent had any luck.
All help appreciated.

Comment: what are you asking, exactly?  What information are you trying to obtain?  Are you trying to add links to other posts?

Comment: @Jonesy Im trying to have the select details page so the information that user wanted but i also what to show four more links to posts that are in the database. A bit like bbc news where when your on the selected news page, it shows a column of latest stories on the right hand side. with links to other news stories

Comment: Handle the `Details` page as you are, but in the view, add a `@Html.Action()` method that calls a separate child method that returns a partial view containing the 4 links

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't very clear. I'm assuming you are trying to display links to four other posts on one post's details page.

In this case you have to create a view-model class that will be returned from your `Details` action to the view. Something like this:

```
public class PostDetailsViewModel
{
    public Post MainPost { get; set; }
    public List<Post> OtherPosts { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your controller action you would populate this model:

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    Post mainPost = db.Posts.Find(id);

    if (mainPost == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    var otherPosts = (from p in db.Posts
                      orderby p.DateAdded descending
                      select p).Take(4).ToList();

    var model = new PostDetailsViewModel
    {
        MainPost = mainpost,
        OtherPosts = otherPosts
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Make sure to update your `Details` view to accept `PostDetailsViewModel` as its model.

Comment: thank you, this looks like the sort of thing i was looking for, i will try this now